# setText not working for EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to set value for `EditTextPreference` item

with `hostPreference.setText("Not yet set");`

But text is not showing

[image]

I want to show it like `Use Name` here

[image]

```
public class HostSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "SettingActivity";
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "HostSettingActivity Started");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPrefs = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences(); 
        setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "On Destroy");
    }

    private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy() {

        // Root
        PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

        PreferenceCategory dialogBasedPrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
        dialogBasedPrefCat.setTitle("Host Settings");
        root.addPreference(dialogBasedPrefCat);

        EditTextPreference hostPreference = new EditTextPreference(this);
        hostPreference.setKey("host");
        hostPreference.setDialogTitle("Host");
        hostPreference.setText("Not yet set");
        hostPreference.setDefaultValue("http://example.com");
        hostPreference.setSummary("Set host");
        dialogBasedPrefCat.addPreference(hostPreference);

        EditTextPreference portPreference = new EditTextPreference(this);
        portPreference.setKey("port");
        portPreference.setDialogTitle("Port");
        portPreference.setDefaultValue("8080");
        portPreference.setSummary("Set port");
        dialogBasedPrefCat.addPreference(portPreference);

        hostPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) preference;

                String newHostValue = newValue.toString();
                Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "New Host: "+newHostValue);
                etp.setText(newHostValue);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that `"Not yet set"` is not appearing when you click the `Set host` preference? Where should `setText` take effect and what result do you expect?

Comment: Does setting the default value solve the problem?

Comment: @Knickedi I want `Not yet set` to come just like `User Name` here http://www.cre8ive.kr/blog/wp-content/uploads/android_prefs_3.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text is not seen in EditTextPreference, but can be edited.

What is seen is **TITLE**, and it is set by setTitle.

If you want to display your edited text in title, you must set it as title yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) with [setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setTitle%28int%29)...